# Variable 'theData' used before being initialized, How should I fix

Tags: swift, apollo

I am trying to Apollo framework and a graphql api to obtain the data then return it.  Once I have the data in another swift file, I want to call on certain parts of the data and assign it to a variable.  The errors I get is variable used before it is initialized.  and if try to return the variable from within the closure I get "Unexpected Non-Void Return Value In Void Function ".  I heard of ways to get around that error but I don't completely understand it and how it works with my code.  If you need more code or context you can message me and I can share my GitHub repo. Sorry if the code is bad, please don't roast me.  I am still a beginner.

```
import Foundation
import Apollo

struct AniListAPI {
    let aniListUrl = "https://graphql.anilist.co"
    
    func ObtainData(AnimeID: Int)-> QueryQuery.Data{
        
        var theData: QueryQuery.Data
        
        let theInfo = QueryQuery(id: AnimeID)
        
            
            
            GraphClient.fetch(query: theInfo) { result in
                
                switch result {
                
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("A big No no happened \(error)")
                    
                case .success(let GraphQLResult):
                    guard let Info = GraphQLResult.data else {return}
                    
                    theData = Info
                    
                }
                
        }
        
        return theData
        
    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Start here http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/ and read this and the next two articles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unexpected Non-Void Return Value In Void Function.**

> The reason you're getting this warning is because you can't return value from inside the closure. Use closure instead of returning value.

```
func ObtainData(AnimeID: Int, completion: @escaping (Data) -> Void) {

   var TheData: QueryQuery.Data
        
        let TheInfo = QueryQuery(id: AnimeID)
        
        GraphClient.fetch(query: TheInfo) { result in
            switch result {
            
            case .failure(let error):
                print("A big no no happened retard \(error)")
                
            case .success(let GraphQLResult):
                guard let Info = GraphQLResult.data else {return}
                
                TheData = Info
                completion(TheData)
            }
            
        }    
}
```

and call it like..

```
ObtainData(AnimeID: 123) { (anyData) in
    print (anyData)
    // continue your logic
}
```